# Make vectors of unequal length equal in length by reducing the size of the largest ones

Tags: matlab, vector

I am reading 5 columns from a .txt file to 5 vectors.

Sometimes some vectors are one element larger than others, so I need to check if they are all of equal length, and if not, I have to find which ones are the largest and delete their last element. I think I should be able to do this without loops. I was originally thinking of using `find` in combination with `isequal` but `isequal` only returns a logical, and does not provide any information on which vectors are the largest.

```
[Seconds,Sensor1VStatic,Sensor2VPulsed,TemperatureC,RelativeHumidity] = importfile(path);
```

Then depending on what vectors are longer by one element, I will do, for example

```
Seconds(end) = [];
Sensor1VStatic(end) = [];
```

If Seconds and Sensor1VStatic are longer than the other vectors by one element

Comment: Please give a short code example of the vectors you have, and how you would like to compare them. It will then be straightforward to give you your answer. Is this a cell array with 6 elements - each element containing a vector of variable length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume your vectors are in a cell array `A`:

```
A = {[1 2 3], [1 2 3 4], [1 2 3 4 5]};
```

You can get the size of each vector with

```
sz = cellfun(@(x)size(x,2), A);
```

Which will return (for the above example)

```
sz = [ 3 4 5]
```

Now you can find the shortest vector:

```
minLength = min(sz);
```

And finally, make all vectors this length:

```
B = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)x(1:minLength), A, 'uniformoutput', false))';
```

There may be more elegant ways (and note that `cellfun` really is doing "implicit looping")

Applying this to your (now expanded) example, you could probably assign the output of `importfile` directly to the cell array - or you can do it as a separate line:

```
A = {Seconds,Sensor1VStatic,Sensor2VPulsed,TemperatureC,RelativeHumidity};
```

But it all becomes a lot of work. Instead you could do:

```
minLength = min(size(Seconds,1), size(Sensor1VStatic,1), size(Sensor2VPulsed,1), ...

Seconds = Seconds(1:minLength);
...
```

There is scope for some cleverness but it won't make things more readable, and it won't save time in the long run...